# Maximization using lsqnon matlab - non linear least squares fitting

Tags: matlab, least-squares, nonlinear-functions

I am trying to maximize a certain quantity using the 'lsqnonlin' function in matlab. Thus, I am trying to minimize the negative of the objective function. However, the lsqnonlin seems to minimize the function and not maximize. I am unable to figure out Where I am going wring in this regard. Any help is appreciated.

Actual problem : I want to maximize the magnitude of gradient of an image - final_Image. I want to do this by weighing the individual images that are combined to get the final_Image.

The code is as below -

```
        options = optimoptions(@lsqnonlin,'Algorithm','levenberg-                                 
                                                       marquardt');
        weights = lsqnonlin(@myfun,initWeights,[],[],options);

        function [F] = myfun(initWeights) 

                for k = 1:numImages
                 newarray(:,:,k) = initWeights(k) * (warpedImages(:,:,k));
                end

                tempImage = median(newarray,3);
                [m,d] = imgradient(tempImage);

                F = -1*m;      

         end
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `lsqnonlin` indeed minimizes the gradient, instead you can use `fminunc`, calculate the magnitude yourself and minimize the negative of the magnitude (which is the same as maximising the magnitude)

Comment: Thank you! Seem to work better than LM.

Comment: @ashp You may consider creating an answer yourself. It may be useful to others.